# React native switch between screens based on login token

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am building a react native app and I am new to it. I have 3 files currently -

1) App.js

2) Login.js

3) FlightList.js

When I have not logged in, I need to show login screen. When I log in, I need to store the token and display Flights list screen.

This is my code -

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './Login';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        //Check if token is there and if there show flight list screen else login screen
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Login.js

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  AsyncStorage,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {
    StackNavigator,
  } from 'react-navigation';
  import FlightList from './FlightList';


  const FlightListScreen = StackNavigator({
    FlightList: { screen: FlightList }
  });

const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access_token';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      error: ""
    }
  }


async storeToken(accessToken){
      try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
      } catch (error) {
          console.log("something went wrong");
      }
    }

  async onLoginPressed() {
    try {
      const reqOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({

            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,

        })
      };

      console.log("error of json is " + JSON.stringify(reqOptions))
      let response = await fetch('https://...login', reqOptions);

      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        const body = await response.json();
          this.storeToken(body.token);
          this.props.navigation.navigate('FlightListScreen');
      } else {
          //Handle error
          let error = res;
          throw error;
      }
    } catch(error) {
        this.setState({error: error});
        console.log("error " + error);
    }
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      //view here
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

FlightList.js

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  AsyncStorage,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {
    StackNavigator,
  } from 'react-navigation';

const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access_token';

export default class FlightList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }


async getToken() {
    try {
        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        console.log("token is" + token);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error while getting token");
    }
 }

 async getFlights() {
    try {
        const reqOptions = {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            // no body since it is GET call

          })
        };

        let response = await fetch('https://.../flights', reqOptions);

        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
          const body = await response.json();
          //update the view
        } else {
            //Handle error
            let error = res;
            throw error;
        }
      } catch(error) {
          this.setState({error: error});
          console.log("error " + error);
      }
 }



 componentDidMount(){
    getFlights();
  }
}
```

My questions is-

1) In App.js how can  I check if token is there and if there show flight list screen else login screen

2) Also the getToken() method how can I use it globally since I need it as header for all the API calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two other files, the first one is a utility file contains all your necessary functions you need to define global. For example your getToken will be like this:

```
export default class Utility {

    static async getToken() {
        try {
            let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            return token
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error while getting token");
            return 'error
        }
    }
}
```

If you use `static` before your function, you can use that function every where you import `Utility` file.

and for your first question... you can make an splash screen and check the token and decide to navigate to which page. I advise you to create a file for your api requests and another file for router. you can define all routing definition in router.js and start app with it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, TabRouter, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Splash from './../views/SplashScreen'
import Login from './../views/Login'
import Verification from './../views/Verification'
import Home from './../views/Home'
import Contents from './../views/Contents'
import ContentList from './../views/ContentList'
import MessageInbox from './../views/MessageInbox'

export default class AppRouter extends Component {

    public static Routes = StackNavigator({
    SplashScreen: { screen: Splash },
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Verification: { screen: Verification },
    Private: {
        screen: DrawerNavigator({
            Main: {
                screen: StackNavigator({
                    Home: { screen: Home },
                    Contents: { screen: Contents },
                    ContentList: { screen: ContentList },
                }, { initialRouteName: 'Home' })
            },
            MessageInbox: { screen: MessageInbox },
        }, { initialRouteName: 'Main' })
    }
}, { initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen' })

render() {
    return (
        <View></View>
    )
}

}
```

and index.js will be:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppRouter from './../router/routes';
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppRouter.Routes />
        )
    }
}
```

I hope i can help you

**EDIT:**

If you use AppRouter, it will be the starter of your app and the first page called by it so it has a `navigation` `prop`. If you want to navigate to each page, you can just use `this.props.navigation.navigate('FlightList')` . remember that if you are using a component in a page and you want to navigate from this component, you need to pass `this.props.navigation` as a `prop` to that component and then, it can change the stack navigation.
in your case, your pages will be something like this...:

Router.js

```
export default class AppRouter extends Component {

public static Routes = StackNavigator({
    SplashScreen: { screen: Splash },
    Login: { screen: Login },
    FlightList: { screen: FlightList},
}, { initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen' })

render() {
    return (
        <View></View>
    )
}
}
```

SplashScreen.js:

```
export default class SplashScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let token = Check token...
    if (token) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('FlightList')
    } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i have a question. In my Login.js file, once successfully logged in, I want to navigate to flight list.js screen. Using this AppRouter, how can I navigate?

Comment: I keep getting this error whenever I start the app - TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'n.render()')

Answer (score 0):

So I have a very similar problem. I solved it by creating a loading screen and on componentDidMount I called a function that like your getToken request fetches the token it also makes a decision once I have a value back from storage to go to the login page or my other page based on if I get a value back or not.

Comment: How did you fix the back button PRess?

Comment: @Julia could you elaborate a little more? Just want to make sure we are on the same page

Comment: I have a splash screen, login screen and flight list screen. The splash screen decides in componentDidMount do I have a token. If yes goto flight list screen else goto login screen. How do you handle back button press here?

Comment: @Julia So there are two places you could handle this. I have a `BackHandler.addEventListener`. This calls my redux action to go back. You could either implement the check here or in the action itself. I basically check and say hey before you pop off a route check to make sure that this isn't the loading screen, or that the screen I am popping to isn't the loading screen if that makes sense.